# How do I log the execution of programs within a directory regardless of shell?

Tags: linux, security, unix, filesystems, logging

I'm curious when exactly a particular directory is being used and when it is loaded into memory.  Is there a way to place a low level hook in the linux file system that says when a file with execution option is read log this event.

Other questions highlight [audit tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206159/how-to-track-log-commands-executed-on-a-shell) or tracking within a particular shell. In my mind the perfect solution would lock executables unless the log transaction is successful and is triggered by the presence of a config file (ie executabletracker.conf).

Comment: `Regardless of shell ` ? . I think shell should be taken into consideration due to system and portability dependency stuff.

Comment: Ok ummm what if we go with bash in most recent LTS version of ubuntu?

Comment: A *directory* is never "loaded into memory". You can use the `inotify` API to watch file system events like file read access (and log them). I am not sure why you think locking has anything to do with this.

Comment: I don’t think it’s related to locking... that’s what I wish to implement. Thanks for the inotify mention that’s probably helpful. Pseudo code for what I was thinking: inotify event for file with execution, if directory is flagged for monitoring then interrupt execution and log the execution with meta data, resume execution.